# Bootstrap Collapse more than one div showing on click

Tags: bootstrap-4

Issue:
1. Click on first button, div appears. 
2. Click on second button, next div appears. First div also appears.
3. Click on third button, third div appears, so does second and first.

I want to ensure when a button is clicked, all divs are collapsed except the one clicked on.

```
    <div class="container">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <div  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">1</div >
    <div  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">2</div >
    <div  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">3</div >
    <div  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">4</div >
   <div  class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5">5</div >
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    A
  </div>


  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
   B
  </div>  <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
   C
  </div>
    </div>  <div id="demo4" class="collapse">
   D
  </div>
  </div>  <div id="demo5" class="collapse">
   E
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErwZpx

Answer (score 0):

From this answer on Stack Overflow (also a duplicate): [Collapsible Buttons - Bootstrap 3.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932478/collapsible-buttons-bootstrap-3-3-4)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
        <button id="a" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AA" data-parent="#container">
          A
        </button>
        <button id="b" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BB" data-parent="#container">
          B
        </button>
    </p>

    <div class="collapse" id="AA">
      <div class="card card-block">
          bla bla bla A
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="BB">
      <div class="card card-block">
         bla bla bla B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Edit: with div instead of button:

```html
From this answer on Stack Overflow (also a duplicate): Collapsible Buttons - Bootstrap 3.3.4

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
        <div id="1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" data-parent="#container">
          1
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" data-parent="#container">
          2
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" data-parent="#container">
          3
        </div>
        <div id="4" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4" data-parent="#container">
          4
        </div>
        <div id="5" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5" data-parent="#container">
          5
        </div>
    </p>

    <div class="collapse" id="demo">
      <div class="card card-block">
          A
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="demo2">
      <div class="card card-block">
         B
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
      <div class="card card-block">
          C
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
      <div class="card card-block">
          D
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
      <div class="card card-block">
          E
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: <div class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">1</div>

Comment: How would it work if  i use a div instead of a button?

Comment: For some reason it still doesn’t work for me. I have a very similar concept to the above however I can’t paste the whole thing as it’s to long. When you click on first div. it opens up the correct associated div. when you click on div2 it keeps div1 data and has div2 data underneath. Only when I click on div1 again it removes the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry friend, I'm stumped on this one.